# kendoAutoComplete options like dataTextField?

Tags: kendo-ui

I Have problem with my kendoAutoComplete i want to bind two fields to kendoAutoComplete, now I can bind one field name to dataTextField but for another field like id i dont have any other option, Following is my code

```
var alld="";
function getData(req) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'BookingCity.asmx/GetAllCityBus',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                minLength: 1,
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                data: "{'prefixText':'" + req + "'}",
                success: function(response) {
                    alld = response.d;


                                   },
                error: function(xhr, status) {
                    alert("error");
                }

            });
        }   
 $("#totext").kendoAutoComplete({
                dataSource: {
                    read: getData($("#totext").attr("value")),
                    data: alld

                },
                minLength: 2,
                placeholder: "Select city...",
                dataTextField: "Name",
                dataTextField:"Id"


            });
```

Comment: Are you wanting to enable the user to type in either an Id or a Name and have the kendoAutoComplete handle both? Or do you need to return a value that corresponds with the dataTextField (like the Id) so you can identify the selected objects?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **template** to achieve this:

```
$("#totext").kendoAutoComplete({
            template: "#=Name# #=Adress#",
            //.. rest of the options
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for `dataValueField:"Id"`

**NOTE:**

dataValueField is not used in kendoAutoComplete (my apologies). It was on the demo page on the Kendo UI website by mistake. It seems a dropdownlist or combobox can be used instead.

*This is assuming you need to return a value that corresponds with the dataTextField (like the Id).*

You can read more about it on the [Kendo UI Forums - DataValueField does exist ?](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/autocomplete/datavaluefield-does-exist.aspx)

or see this relevant excerpt:

> The autocomplete UI widget persists only the selected text. Actually the you can post only the content of the input element. This is the expected behavior. As to the demos, the "dataValueField" is left by mistake and we will fix that for the next release of KendoUI.
>
> In order to achieve your goal, **you will need to use dropdownlist or combobox**, which persist the selected id.
>
> Regards,
> Georgi Krustev
> the Telerik team

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @valex Sorry, you were right to delete my answer. However I have amended it and left a comment to the author as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this? You can only bind one field to the dataTextField property, so if you want to show two, just add an additional calculated field to your datasource that contains the concatenated values of both fields and bind to that.